# How would you create a high gloss finish on furniture?

Tags: painting, wooden-furniture, sanding, finish

From a smooth lacquered finish like this:
[image: Nexera Platform Bed]

To a high gloss like this:

[image: IKEA Kitchen Cabinet]

How would I get create a finish like the picture above when starting with a smooth lacquer finished piece of furniture (i.e. IKEA Malm wooden furniture)? I know it is a multiple step process but I don't know what the best approach is. What tools/products would you need?

I'm a beginner to diy home improvement so any small tips/steps would be extremely helpful!

Comment: This question might be better suited for the [Woodworking SE](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I do know many of these ikea finishes are not a series of liquid finishes, but rather a heat applied polypropylene or similar plastic. This is something that is not easily reproducible in a home environment. Classic "piano black" for instance can take HUNDREDs of coats on wood, with polishing between. You could go down a route like that, or you could use melamine on MDF, or simply use a good white paint and a hardener.

Answer (score 2):

If your existing finish truly is lacquer, all you would need to do is apply additional coat(s) of high gloss clear lacquer.

Always use the very best brush you can afford, or spray it. Lay the material flat, for best results. If you have no experience with this type of finish or with the application techniques mentioned, you should practice practice practice on some sample pieces first (and read a book about working with lacquer, maybe).